# Changing contents of a tsx file through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a requirement to change the contents of **config.tsx** file that contains values like:

```
const authData = {
    base_uri: 'https://development-api.com.au',

    customLib: {
        redirect_uri: 'https://another-development-api.com.au'
    }
}
export default authData;
```

I want to change this content using a shell script and save the file. Changed content can look like:

```
const authData = {
    base_uri: 'https://production-api.com.au',

    customLib: {
        redirect_uri: 'https://another-production-api.com.au'
    }
}
export default authData;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean changing every `development` with `production`?

Comment: yes @FrancescoLucianò

Comment: I am able to see the printed output to stdout when i use it without the `-i`.
However, when I try this with `-i` it gives me an error.
`sed: 1: "config.tsx": invalid command code o`

I am using mac os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -i 's/development/production/g' config.tsx
```

The `-i` option will edit the file in place. If you first want to try the command to see if it works the way you want, use it without the `-i`. The output will be printed to stdout.

Comment: I am able to see the printed output to stdout when i use it without the `-i`.
However, when I try this with `-i` it gives me an error.
`sed: 1: "config.tsx": invalid command code o`

I am using mac os.

Comment: What I hadn’t realised is that on the Mac version of sed the ‘-i’ flag has a mandatory suffix.
So for my case, `sed -i "" 's/development/production/g' config.tsx` worked!!